# Cannot list AWS S3 public folder items when using Android Amplify?

Tags: android, amazon-s3, aws-amplify

I am using AWS' Amplify Android library in my app, and I'm trying to list items
from an S3 bucket just as mentioned in the [Storage Amplify docs](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/storage/list/q/platform/android):

```kotlin
Amplify.Storage.list("/",
    { result ->
        Log.i("MyAmplifyApp", "Total Items : " + result.items.size)
        result.getItems().forEach { item ->
            Log.i("MyAmplifyApp", "Item: " + item.getKey())
        }
    },
    { error ->
        Log.e("MyAmplifyApp", "List failure", error)
        Toast.makeText(this, "Something went wrong. Please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show()
    }
)
```

**No matter what path I provide, I get back 0 items. Any ideas? There is no
error printed in logcat.**

**Note:**

1. User role/policy has acccess rights to S3
2. Cognito auth flow works fine using unauthenticated users or even
   authenticated users
3. Path exists
4. Bucket exists and has objects.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Can you share any error messages you are seeing?

Comment: @RichardMcClellan there is no error. it goes to success and I am getting total items :0 but in AWS I have a list of items

Comment: Can you share more info about how you created your bucket, and how you added items to it?  Was it via the amplify CLI, or some other way?  If this is an existing bucket created outside of Amplify, you can use it by following [this guide](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/storage/existing-resources/q/platform/android)

Comment: I am using amplify CLI only

Comment: Same here, i am receiving 0 items no matter what i try, My IAM role is configured to do anything on S3 and authentication process goes fine, and there are s3 items in the path. i tried various paths nothing seemed to work!

Comment: @Mercury if you got any solution paste it here

Answer (score 2):

I'm a little late to the party, but came across exact same problem today.

It turns out, that inside your S3 bucket if you want to list public files **you must provide folder named 'public'**.

I wasted on it about 5 hours today modifying ACLs, and trying other options, and found answer here [Github for Amplify-js](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/3143). I hope this will save others some time.

Answer (score -1):

I am getting a list of images inside the folder of my bucket.

```kotlin
Amplify.Storage.list("/folderName",
    { result ->
        Log.i("MyAmplifyApp", "Total Items : " + result.items.size)
        result.getItems().forEach { item ->
            Log.i("MyAmplifyApp", "Item: " + item.getKey())
        }
    },
    { error ->
        Log.e("MyAmplifyApp", "List failure", error)
        Toast.makeText(this, "Something went wrong. Please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show()
    }
)
```

Comment: Why did it not work so far? and what did you do that solved the issue?

Comment: getting a list of an inside folder of the bucket